# How to get string from SendMessage request (of a external exe) in c++

Tags: c++, string, winapi, sendmessage, lparam

I have two executables. I want to use one to get string from another one. In other words, I want to make a InterProcess Communication.
I tried ***SendMessage*** by using ***(char*)lParam*** in *WndProc*. However, it doesn't work. ***(char*)lParam*** makes a runtime error.
Here is part of my code:

the sender of SendMessage:

```
string s="12345";
SendMessage(hwnd,M_WR_SHELL,0,(LPARAM)s.c_str());
```

the receiver of SendMessage(in WndProc):

```
case M_WR_SHELL: {
    string s;
    s=(char*)lParam;
    MessageBox(NULL, s.c_str(),"THAT'S GOOD'",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

I searched for the question. Some answers is like "They don't share the same memory space." However, I don't know how to deal with it.
If using ***SendMessage*** is not proper, how can I make it?

PS: I'm using TDM-GCC and don't want to use MFC and even VC++. If possible, please don't give me solutions through them. **;p**

Thanks,
W. Xie

Comment: Use WM_COPYDATA it's designed to do the job: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten : It seems that WM_COPYDATA doesn't support return value. However, I need to return something to the request sender. What's more, I need to send more than one argument to get the return value.

Comment: If you need to send a return do so by `WM_COPYDATA` in the other direction.  `WM_COPYDATA` sends a block a data what you put in it is your "message".  If you have requirements for multiple messages then invent a simple message format eg 1 byte - message ID; 1 byte - message length; message body. etc

Comment: fyi: Inter-Process Communication (IPC) on MS-Windows from easy to hard: `WM_COPYDATA`; named pipes; TCP/IP; COM; RPC; shared-memory (although this is relative to your experience with the above mechanisms).

Comment: @RichardCritten That seems too arcane and I may not be able to understand it in a short time :) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you need to learn new things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use shared memory.I recommend using WM_COPYDATA instead of a user-defined message.  WM_COPYDATA can only be sent via SendMessage() or SendMessageTimeout() and Windows will take care of copying the data into the receiving process address space.

Comment: See above: It seems that WM_COPYDATA doesn't support return value. However, I need to return something to the request sender. What's more, I need to send more than one argument to get the return value.

Comment: And maybe sometimes it will receive request from more than one process.

Comment: @谢卓然 you can use SendMessage with COPYDATASTRUCT, struct which consist your return data. You can't change SendMessage return type. And by WM_COPYDATA you will get return value in Boolean.In other hand I strongly recommend to use SendMessageTimeout(SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG) rather than SendMessage()! Otherwise if the receiving process is hanging the sending process will also hang eternally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it.

Comment: That's self-contradictory: If you insist, that using shared memory were strictly required, your conclusion to use a scheme that is based on copying data cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WM_COPYDATA (the easiest) or shared memory via [file mapping functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx).
My own [USM](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835818/Ultimate-Shared-Memory-A-flexible-class-for-sharin)  might help, but generally you need to invest more time in IPC mechanisms since you appear to come from another OS (hence the note about Visual Studio). IPC in Windows is not a simple task.

Comment: Well, I think the file mapping function may not be simple. And see above: It seems that WM_COPYDATA doesn't support return value. However, I need to return something to the request sender. What's more, I need to send more than one argument to get the return value.

Comment: Maybe sometimes it will receive request from more than one process.

Comment: Just a note that you seem to come from linux where processes communicate with each other more frequently, in Windows, this is not the case.